# Measure Theory: $\sigma$-finite $\implies$ $\sigma$-subadditive over $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, probability-theory, measure-theory

Is the following theorem true? If so, does my proof prove it?

***Theorem:***

Let $\mathcal{A} \subset 2^{\Omega}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra and let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal{A}$. If $\mu$ is

1. $\sigma$-finite, that is, $\exists\{A_{i}\}_{i\geq{1}}\subset\mathcal{A}$ s.t. $\Omega = \bigcup\limits_{i\geq{1}}A_{i}$ and $\mu(A_{i})<\infty$
2. additive, that is, $\{A_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}\subset\mathcal{A} \implies \mu\biggl(\biguplus\limits_{i=1}^{n}A_{i}\biggr) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\mu(A_{i})$

then $\mu$ is $\sigma$-subadditive, that is, if $\{A_{i}\}_{i\geq{1}}\subset\mathcal{A}$ is a countable covering of $A\in\mathcal{A}$ then $\mu(A)\leq\sum\limits_{i\geq{1}}\mu(A_{i})$.

Note: $\biguplus$ represents the disjoint union.

***Proof:***

From the hypothesis there exists $\{A_{i}\}_{i\geq{1}}\subset\mathcal{A}$ s.t. $\Omega=\bigcup\limits_{i\geq{1}}A_{i}$. Let $B_{1} = A_{1}$ and $B_{i}=A_{i}\setminus\biggl(\bigcup\limits_{1\leq{j}<i}A_{j}\biggr)$

$\implies A_{i}=A_{i}\bigcap\biggl( \bigcup\limits_{1\leq{j}<i}A_{j} \biggr) \bigcup B_{i} \implies B_{i}\subset A_{i}$

$\implies \mu(B_{i})\leq \mu(A_{i})$

therefore, $\mu\biggl(\biguplus\limits_{i\geq{1}}B_i\biggr)=\sum\limits_{i\geq{1}}\mu(B_i)\leq\sum\limits_{j\geq{1}}\mu(A_{j})$. Since $\mu$ is defined over $\mathcal{A}$ a similar construction can be made for any $A\in\mathcal{A}$; hence, $\mu$ is $\sigma$-subadditive on $\mathcal{A}$ if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite and additive.

Comment: I can't really see why is it important for $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ to be generated by a semiring. In fact, every $\sigma$-algebra is a semiring, so it is automatically generated by a semiring. And since the assumptions on the measure $\mu$ are concerning the elements of the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathcal A)$, why not just state the problem for a measure $\mu$ on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$?

Comment: There are some details to be filled. Such as why $\mu(B_i)\leq \mu(A_i)$, which is a consequence of the finite additivity and that $$A_i=A_i\cap\left(\bigcup_{1\leq j <i}A_j\right)\ \cup\ B_i,$$ disjointed union.

Comment: Now, when you use that equality with the measure of the sets $B_i$ you are using that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive. You can't use that.

Comment: Also, you dont use the $\sigma$-finiteness in any step. It is important.

Comment: @AndréPorto Can you elaborate on the " equality with the measure of the sets $B_{i}$ you are using that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive". I used the $\sigma$-finiteness in the first line of the proof...

Comment: Yes, $\mu\biggl(\biguplus\limits_{i\geq{1}}B_i\biggr)=\sum\limits_{i\geq{1}}\mu(B_i)$ assumes implicitly that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive. But your assumptions only require $\mu$ to be finitely additive.

Comment: Can you be more specific in which part you used the $\sigma$-finiteness?

Comment: You only broke the set in a countable amount of sets. You didnt use that the measures of these sets are finite.

Comment: @AndréPorto I used the $\sigma$-finiteness when I stated the existence of a cover $\{A_{i}\}_{i\geq{1}}$ for $\Omega$.

Comment: Look, this covering of $\Omega$ always exists. Just pick $A_i=\Omega$ for all $i\geq1$. The sets $A_i$ need not to be disjointed, so we could pick all of them equal to $\Omega$.

Comment: @AndréPorto Because $\Omega\in\mathcal{A}$, I forgot about that... from $\sigma$-finiteness we know that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ since $\Omega\in\mathcal{A}$; therefore $\sum\limits_{i\geq{1}}\mu(B_{i})\leq\sum\limits_{i\geq{1}}\mu(A_{i}) < \infty$. Can I use this to show $\mu(\biguplus\limits_{i\geq{1}}B_{i}) \leq \sum\limits_{i\geq{1}}\mu(A_{i})$?

Comment: It isn't true that $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$. What I said in the previous comment is that $\sigma$-finiteness is not necessary to pick the covering $\{A_i\}$. A measure is $\sigma$-finite if it can be broken into countable pieces and each of these pieces have finite measure. For example, the usual measure on $\mathbb R$, it is not finite, but $\mathbb R$ is the union of the intervals $[-n,n]$, which have finite measure. So the usual measure on $\mathbb R$ is not finite but it's $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: @AndréPorto So since $\Omega$ can be covered by countably many sets $\{A_{i}\}_{i\geq{1}}$ all of which with finite measure and $B_{i}\subset A_{i} \implies \mu(B_{i})\leq\mu(A_{i}) < \infty \implies \mu(B_{i})<\infty$ and $\{B_{i}\}_{i\geq{1}}$ is a countable set.

Comment: The assumption on $\sigma$-finiteness doesn't say that ANY countable covering $\{A_i\}$ of $\Omega$ satisfies $\mu(A_i)<\infty$ for any $i\geq 1$. NO. It says that THERE EXISTS a countable covering  $\{A_i\}$ of $\Omega$ such that $\mu(A_i)<\infty$ for any $i\geq 1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85020/discussion-between-griffy-and-andre-porto).